# How do I set the path correctly so that my code works for subfolders?

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a code that allows me to search and replace in multiple Excel files within a folder and its subfolders.

However, this does not work properly yet, because I think that the following line contains an error:

```
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($Path + [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName("$item"))
```

All Excel files located directly in the main "test" folder are opened and saved correctly. However, the Excel files in the subfolders are not opened and saved.

This is the code:

```
$Path = "G:\test"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path G:\test -Filter *.xlsx -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force

ForEach ($item in $files) { 
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $false
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($Path + [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName("$item"))
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$SearchString = "Test" #String to Find
$Range = $Worksheet.Range("A1:DZ100000").EntireColumn #Range of Cells to look at
$Search = $Range.find($SearchString)

if ($search -ne $null) {
    $FirstAddress = $search.Address
    do {
        $Search.value() = $Search.value().Replace($SearchString, "Test2") #String to Update
        $search = $Range.FindNext($search)
    } while ( $search -ne $null -and $search.Address -ne $FirstAddress)
}

$WorkBook.Save()
$WorkBook.Close()
[void]$excel.quit()
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Why don't you use `$Item.FullName`

Comment: Frankly, I am a complete beginner and have slightly customized this script with the help of Google. Line 2 should be correct. But with the line I described I don't know any further. Would it be possible that you correct the line?

Comment: Use `$Item.FullName` instead of your *construction* of a file path!